# min.insync.replicas vs. unclean.leader.election

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to achieve reliable data delivery using a Kafka topic.

If I set `min.insync.replicas = 2`, may I not change the default value of `unclean.leader.election.enable` (default value is `true`)?

Or should I additionally set `unclean.leader.election.enable` to false?

If `min.insync.replicas` equal 2, is there a risk of data loss because of unclean leader election?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, whether the data will be lost depends on the circumstances. I could explain this through the scenario:

```
min.insync.replicas=2 && unclean.leader.election.enable=true (It is default value)
```

[image]

In these case, data(message 3) will be lost. Since unclean leader election was allowed, Broker 1 is made the new leader even though it was not in-sync with the other broker. Otherwise, While **unclean.leader.election.enable** is a cluster-wide setting, *you can override this configuration per topic*.
The image is from [Kafka In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kafka-in-action) book.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set the value, it'll take the default, of course.

Those settings are for different purposes, though; setting one won't override the other.

If you have 2 in-sync replicas (and your producers have ack'd all their messages), then in theory, you would always have at least one clean leader that can be elected.

Comment: Cloudera docs also mention some producer and broker settings - https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.0/topics/kafka_faq.html#concept_g5s_tpl_d2b__section_l5s_tpl_d2b

Answer (score 0):

```
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
```

will allow non ISR replicas to become leader, ensuring availability but  consistency is not guaranteed  as data loss will occur.